# Avoid duplicate type alias in Scala class and companion object

Tags: scala, companion-object, type-alias

I'm a newbie in Scala, and I have a Scala program with a class and a companion object, and I want to use a type alias that is used :

1. To define the methods of the class.
2. Also I want to use the alias outside the class. For that I find useful to define the alias in the companion object, to import the alias from the companion object. I also have some implicits defined in the companion object so this is just natural.

The concrete code is available at https://github.com/juanrh/Surus/blob/1cfd55ed49c4d1b22e53babe07bcf44fd74e3072/src/main/scala/org/surus/spark/SurusRDDFunctions.scala, the type alias is PMMLPrediction and the class is SurusRDDFunctions. Currently the code works but I have defined the alias both in the class and the companion, which is not very nice. If I remove the definition of the alias in the class then the class is not able to find it, which seems weird. So I think I'm probably doing something wrong, any ideas?

Thanks a lot in advance for your help!

Greetings,

Juan

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given the companion object

```
object Example {
  type MyString = String
}
```

You can access the type directly through to the companion object

```
class Example (val name: Example.MyString) { }
```

Or by importing it from the companion object

```
class Example {
  import Example._

  val name: MyString = "example"
}
```